# How to change the code after 'Recording Macro'?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use 'record macro' option to organize the data file easily. 
For example, I saved a macro and the code was as below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[23]C[0])"
Range("B2").Select
```

I want to use it in the code for other cells too. And I copied them and it worked.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[23]C[0])"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[22]C[1])"
Range("B3").Select
```

The problem is because of the "ActiveCell" it sometimes use the code in wrong cells. I tried to change the "ActiveCell" with the cell number but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: I would answer, but I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to put this formula `"=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[22]C[1])"` into a cell `B2` without using `ActiveCell`, you can do `Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[22]C[1])"`. However, this will put the formula into cell `B2` of whatever worksheet and workbook is active whilst the code is running. So it's always good to include a parent workbook and worksheet reference alongside the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have posted enough code here to give you a direct answer for this case, but let us assume the recorded code looks like this:

```
 Range("B2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[23]C[0])"
```

then you can replace it by

```
 Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[23]C[0])"
```

However, since `Range("B2")` is still a shortcut for `ActiveSheet.Range("B2")`, I would recommend to have some code to determine the correct work sheet first, assign it so some variable `sh` of type `Worksheet`, and then write

```
 sh.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VolumeDat!R[3]C[1]:R[23]C[0])"
```

That will make your code more robust against changing the sheet context.